# Storing all entries of an ID in a list within a column in tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

So let's say I have some simple data as follows:

```
ID   value  character
001      A        JABA
002      B        FABA
001      B        RABA
003      D        RIBI
003     TT        LENI
004      A        LENT
001      A        TATA
004      N        YAYA
004      N        YANA
```

And what I want to do (using tidyverse/dplyr) is to create a summarized table of these IDs and their values across the entire table. If the user has duplicates of a value, it should only appear once.

**Expected Output**

```
ID   values
001  [A,B]
002  [B]
003  [D,TT]
004  [A,N]
```

Not overly attached to format but you get the idea :)

Comment: `aggregate(value~ID, unique(df[1:2]), toString)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  distinct(value) %>%
  summarize(val = paste(value, collapse = ", "))

# A tibble: 4 × 2
     ID val  
  <int> <chr>
1     1 A, B 
2     2 B    
3     3 D, TT
4     4 A, N
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need a concateneted string but a vector of unique values

```
tibble(
    id=c(1,1,1,2), 
    value=letters[c(1,1,2,3)]) %>% 
    print() %>% 

# A tibble: 4 x 2
#      id value
#   <dbl> <chr>
# 1     1 a    
# 2     1 a    
# 3     1 b    
# 4     2 c 

    group_by(id) %>% 
    summarise(across(everything(), ~list(unique(.)))) %>% 
    print() %>% 

# A tibble: 2 x 2
#      id value    
#   <dbl> <list>   
# 1     1 <chr [2]>
# 2     2 <chr [1]>

    deframe()

# $`1`
# [1] "a" "b"
#
# $`2`
# [1] "c"
```